# Publishing test results to build after running manual test in MS Test Manager

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

I'm exploring using Microsoft Test Manager as an option for for my company to switch over to. We already use Visual Studio/TFS for our development, source control, builds, scrum process, etc.

I've been able to use Test Manager to run manual tests, but I can't find anyway to publish these results to a build or any easy way to associate these test runs with work items.

The build summary in Visual Studio does show that a test run as having completed after I run a test in MTM against that build, but when I try to view the results I get "Downloading the selected test run failed. Test run XX does not have a run summary attachment. The .trx file is either not published or upgraded."

Is it possible to publish results to TFS after running a manual test in MTM?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-NL/vsmantest/thread/2ffe3e27-216a-4b70-b352-524d8e34f536